# SAPUI5 Navigate to a view in same application by opening a new tab

Tags: sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 application and I need to open a view (View2) by passing some query string parameters from another view (View1) by writing a method in View1 controller.

So far I've done it like below and it works fine when I run the application through webIDE. But when I deploy the application to the cloud platform it gives an error.

Controller js function

```
handleDetailNavPress: function(oEvent) {
            var viewModel = this.getModel();
            var headerInfo = viewModel.getProperty("/HeaderInfo");


            var navUrl = "#detailscreen/params?docNo=" +
                headerInfo.DocNo+ "&docName=" + headerInfo.DocName";

            var url = window.location.href.split('#')[0] + navUrl;
            //Navigate to second view
            sap.m.URLHelper.redirect(url, true);
        }
```

Routing settings in manifest

```
"routing": {            "routes": [
                {
                    "pattern": "viewone",
                    "name": "viewone",
                    "target": "viewone"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "viewtwo/params:?query:",
                    "name": "viewtwo",
                    "target": "viewtwo"
                }           ],
```

Error I got after deploying

> viewSample:112 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '6' of null
>       at getIntentParameter (qcmanager:112)
>       at Object.requestSite (qcmanager:352)
>       at Object.getSiteJson (qcmanager:500)
>       at Object.loadAppSite (qcmanager:567)
>       at qcmanager:745
>       at qcmanager:746

What is the issue. Is there another way to navigate within same app by opening a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a Vi 2 in new tabe there are two options:

1. Either crate a saperate inde.html for that new view and include that view in that index.html (It's basically will work like a saperate SAP UI5 application for user)
   But i will not recomend this one

The other solution is

2. Instead of Using "sap.m.URLHelper", user:
   window.open('[PAth to you Application index file]/[url]', '**_blank**');
   For Example: window.open('https://www.mysapui5app/#podetailscreen/params?docNo=...', '**_blank**');

*Remember, _blank is madatory to open view in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy your application the launchpad the link changes, the second view comes like current URL + `&/`, so you need to check your URL and pass it correctly.
Just change these two variables accordingly:

```
navUrl
URL
```

Also, I would suggest to do cross app navigation as it will be more safer.